# Two developers and entitlements in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working with another developer on an app that requires entitlements. We are using a Git repository, and keep encountering the problem:

> The app ID "com.myCompany.myApp" cannot be registered to your
>   development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to
>   try again

We are in the process of registering a business so we can have an Organization Developer Account and be on the same developer team, but until then are there any workarounds other than having to manually change the Bundle Identifier each time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either share a developer account (username and password) or copy your target, change the identifier and each use your own target.